# How to parse data from different style class at site

Tags: java, parsing

I want to develop simple program that parse my blog and my friends blog visitors made by Java.
 But When I proceed working, I found the problem that each blog has different design and style class name. Like that.

This is My Blog Visitor tag

```
<dl class="list_visitor">
    <dt>Today</dt>
    <dd>34</dd>
</dl>
```

And this is My friend Blog Visitor tag

```
<div class="counter">
      <span>
            <span>TODAY</span>
       11</span>
     <span>
            <span>TOTAL</span>
      1,033</span>
</div>
```

Is there any solution? Please, Help me.

Comment: Write a parser with a "plugin" for each type. The plugin decides whether the fragment matches its expectation and parses, otherwise passes on to the next. Consider a [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Comment: What's plugin's mean? Your words mean I have to prepare setting each tag ??